# Identifying a connector for an AR headset

Tags: connector

I'm trying to identify the connector between the Epson Moverio BT-200 smart glasses (similar to the Google Glass) and the battery pack/touchpad.

[image: Epson Moverio Bt-200 AR glasses]

**Some measurements:**

- 20 pins top
- 20 pins below
- Pitch (between individual pins) - 0.50mm
- Male connector outer height - 3.20mm (0.122 inch)
- Male connector outer width - 16.60 (0.653 inch)
- Male connector inner width (inside the metal part that fits into the female connector) - 11.1mm(0.437 inch)

[image: male connector - close up]

- Female connector inner width - 16.6mm (0.653 inch)
- Female connector inner height - 3.2mm (0.126 inch)

We want to build an inexpensive HDMI interface to use with our DJI phantom 3 pro quadcopter. Would be great if anyone has ideas on how we can identify this connector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer from someone on Reddit.

Looks exactly like the DD2-series connector, made by JAE Electronics.

- DD2 series brochure - http://jae-connector.com/en/pdf/MB-0112-3E_DD2.pdf
- Plug - https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jae-electronics/DD2B040HA2R500/670-1023-1-ND/1283593
- Receptacle - /product-detail/en/jae-electronics/DD2R040HP2R1000/670-1025-1-ND/1283594